# SQL command not properly ended on Live SQL with Subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I get an error

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

when I try to run:

```
select Instructor 
from 
    (select Instructor, count(candidates.Subject) as n 
     from Subjects, candidates 
     where Subjects.Subject =  candidates.Subject
     group by Instructor) as temp;
```

However, the subquery

```
select Instructor, count(candidates.Subject) as n 
from Subjects, candidates 
where Subjects.Subject =  candidates.Subject
group by Instructor;
```

can be run without a problem.

I am not sure where I did wrong.

I found that doing the query without a alias works. Why is that?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the "AS" before TEMP. Because "AS" cannot come after "FROM" keyword.

```
 SELECT INSTRUCTOR
  FROM (  SELECT INSTRUCTOR, COUNT (CANDIDATES.SUBJECT) AS N
            FROM SUBJECTS, CANDIDATES
           WHERE SUBJECTS.SUBJECT = CANDIDATES.SUBJECT
        GROUP BY INSTRUCTOR) TEMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Instructor
FROM   (SELECT Instructor,
               Count(candidates.Subject) AS n
        FROM   Subjects
               INNER JOIN candidates
                       ON Subjects.Subject = candidates.Subject
        GROUP  BY Instructor) AS temp;
```